# Discontinuities in the frequency domain

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, continuous-signals, spectrogram, wave

I'm trying to implement a waveform such the frequency will look like this -

$f(t)=f_0+\left(f_1-f_0\right) e^{\frac{\left(t \pm \delta_t / 2\right)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$

To do so, I calculate it like this -

```
def Gaussian_frequencies( t , f_0 , f_1 , dt , sigma ):
    return  f_0 + (f_1 - f_0)*np.exp(-np.power(t+dt/2,2)/(2*(sigma**2)))

duration = 1e-5
f0 = 90e6                             
f1 = 80e6
delta_t = 0.12*duration    
sigma = 0.194*duration
samplerate = 2**30
t = np.linspace(-duration/2, duration/2 , int(duration*samplerate))
f = Gaussian_frequencies(t, f0, f1, delta_t, sigma)
wave_form = 8000*np.sin(2*np.pi*np.cumsum(f)/samplerate)
```

According to the definition $f=\frac{d\theta}{dt},\theta - phase$

Then when I'm using the spectrogram function I see discontinuities in the frequency domain.

```
win_len = 256 # for better frequency resolution
frequencies_spectugram_256, times, syn_Sxx30 = signal.spectrogram(syn, fs=samplerate, nperseg=win_len, nfft = 256, noverlap=win_len - 1)
```

[image: win len 256, nfft = 256]

Then, I'm changing the 'nfft' parameter and the spectrogram becomes more smooth. [image: win len = 256 , nfft =1024]

Then, just for checking, I'm using winlen = nfft = 1024 and again there exist discontinuities
[image: win ken = nfft = 1024]

Can you tell what is the cause of the discontinuities? Apparently, it has a connection to the nfft parameter. I think it represents the length of the support on the frequency domain of the fft operator.  Is it ok to use this parameter bigger than the win len ?